# How to reformulate or linearize the phrase "become redundant" or "not needed"?

Tags: optimization, constraints, non-convex-optimization, linearization, binary-programming

I am an electrical engineer and currently I have to deal with an optimization problem with a very specific requirement:

$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\mathop {Min}\limits_x }&{f\left( x \right)}\\
{{c_1}:}&{{x_1} + {x_2} \ge 1}\\
{{c_2}:}&{{x_2} + {x_3} \ge 1}\\
{}&{{x_1},{x_2},{x_3} \in \left\{ {0,1} \right\}}
\end{array}$

Particularly, there are some control variables $t_4$ and $t_5$ where ${t_4},{t_5} \in \left\{ {0,1} \right\}$ that literally state the following:

If $t_4=1$ then the constraint $c_1$ is needed to be kept.
If $t_4=0$ then the constraint $c_1$ is not needed to be kept. In other words, $c_1$ becomes redundant and will not participate in the optimization process.

If $t_5=1$ then the constraint $c_2$ is needed to be kept.
If $t_5=0$ then the constraint $c_2$ is not needed to be kept. In other words, $c_2$ becomes redundant and will not participate in the optimization process.

1/ How to linearize these statements and incorporate the corresponding variable $t_4$ and $t_5$ into the optimization problem ?

I am also not sure if we can exploit the fact that all of these variables are binary ${x_1},{x_2},{x_3},{t_4},{t_5} \in \left\{ {0,1} \right\}$ ?

Edited:

$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\mathop {Min}\limits_x }&{f\left( x \right)}\\
{{c_1}:}&{{x_1} + {x_2} \ge 1}\\
{{c_2}:}&{{x_2} + {x_3} \ge 1}\\
{{c_3}:}&{{x_4} + {x_5} \ge {y_1}}\\
{{c_4}:}&{{x_5} + {x_6} \ge {y_2}}\\
{}&{{x_1},{x_2},{x_3} \in \left\{ {0,1} \right\}}\\
{}&{{y_1},{y_2} \in \left\{ {0,1} \right\}}
\end{array}$

2/ I almost forgot about the case of constraint $c_3$ and $c_4$. Under this case how can we repeat the technique in question 1 for the two binary variable $t_6$, $t_7$ ?

If $t_6=1$ then the constraint $c_3$ is needed to be kept. If $t_6=0$ then the constraint $c_3$ is not needed to be kept. In other words, $c_3$ becomes redundant and will not participate in the optimization process.

Similarly for $t_7$, it is the same for $c_4$.

Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original constraint $c_1$ enforces the disjunction $x_1 \lor x_2$.  That is, either $x_1=1 $ or $x_2=1$ (or both).

Your original constraint $c_3$ enforces the implication $y_1 \implies (x_4 \lor x_5)$.  That is, if $y_1 = 1$ then either $x_4=1$ or $x_5=1$ (or both).

You can obtain the desired constraints somewhat automatically via [conjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form).

For the first one:
$$
t_4 \implies (x_1 \lor x_2) \\
\lnot t_4 \lor (x_1 \lor x_2) \\
\lnot t_4 \lor x_1 \lor x_2 \\
(1-t_4) + x_1 + x_2 \ge 1 \\
x_1 + x_2 \ge t_4
$$
It is easy to check the two cases:

- If $t_4=1$ then $x_1+x_2 \ge 1$, as desired.
- If $t_4=0$ then $x_1+x_2 \ge 0$, which is redundant.

For the third one:
$$
(t_6 \land y_1) \implies (x_4 \lor x_5) \\
\lnot (t_6 \land y_1) \lor (x_4 \lor x_5) \\
(\lnot t_6 \lor \lnot y_1) \lor (x_4 \lor x_5) \\
\lnot t_6 \lor \lnot y_1 \lor x_4 \lor x_5 \\
(1-t_6) + (1-y_1) + x_4 + x_5 \ge 1 \\
x_4 + x_5 \ge t_6 + y_1 - 1
$$
It is easy to check the cases:

- If $t_6=y_1=1$, then $x_4+x_5 \ge 1$, as desired.
- If $t_6+y_1=1$, then $x_4+x_5 \ge 0$, which is redundant.
- If $t_6=y_1=0$, then $x_4+x_5 \ge -1$, which is redundant.

Comment: I think there might be something wrong here. This should be conjunctive normal form 
$\left( {\neg x \vee y} \right) \wedge \left( {\neg x \vee \neg y} \right) \wedge \left( {x \vee y} \right)$

and this should be disjunctive normal form $\left( {\neg x \vee y} \right) \vee \left( {\neg x \vee \neg y} \right) \vee \left( {x \vee y} \right)$

Comment: A single disjunction like $x \lor y \lor z$ is also CNF.

Comment: Thank you it is clear now

Answer (score 4):

Replace $c_1$ with $c_1':x_1+x_2\geq t_4$. If $t_4=1$, you recover $c_1$; if $t_4=0$, the constraint becomes $x_1+x_2\geq 0$, which is redundant, since $x_1,x_2\in\{0,1\}$. Similarly, replace $c_2$ with $c_2':x_2+x_3\geq t_5$.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Can you elaborate more on your answer so that it could solve the second case ! I have already upvoted your answer