# Does this binary integer problem has any special structure that can be exploit?

Tags: optimization, integer-programming

I am an electrical engineer and currently I am learning some optimization for my research work. Note that this is a follow up question from my previous question at this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4808675/how-to-reformulate-or-linearize-the-phrase-become-redundant-or-not-needed).

My project requires me to solve this problem and I am not sure about two things:

1/ Does case 1 easier than case 2 or does case 2 easier than case 1 ?

2/ For both cases, are there a special structure in the **matrix $A$** that I can exploit ?

Expoit can mean anything, even if it means that I could solve it more faster or decompose this problem into other smaller subproblems since I have some distributed computing capability.

This is how **case 1** looks:

$\begin{array}{l}
\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\rm{Min}}}&{{x_1} + {x_2} + {x_3} + {x_4} + {x_5} + {x_6}}
\end{array}\\
\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}&{\underbrace {\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&1&0&{}&{}&{}\\
0&1&1&{}&{}&{}\\
{}&{}&{}&1&1&0\\
{}&{}&{}&0&1&1
\end{array}} \right]}_A\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{x_1}}\\
{{x_2}}\\
{{x_3}}\\
{{x_4}}\\
{{x_5}}\\
{{x_6}}
\end{array}} \right] \ge \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
a\\
b\\
c\\
d
\end{array}} \right]}\\
{}&{a + c \le 1}\\
{}&{b + d \le 1}\\
{}&{{x_i},a,b,c,d \in \left\{ {0,1} \right\}}
\end{array}
\end{array}$

This is how **case 2** looks:

$\begin{array}{l}
\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\rm{Min}}}&{{x_1} + {x_2} + {x_3} + {x_4} + {x_5} + {x_6}}
\end{array}\\
\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}&{\underbrace {\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&1&0&{}&{}&{}\\
0&1&1&{}&{}&{}\\
{}&{}&{}&1&1&0\\
{}&{}&{}&0&1&1
\end{array}} \right]}_A\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{x_1}}\\
{{x_2}}\\
{{x_3}}\\
{{x_4}}\\
{{x_5}}\\
{{x_6}}
\end{array}} \right] \ge \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
a\\
b\\
c\\
d
\end{array}} \right]}\\
{}&{a + c = 1}\\
{}&{b + d = 1}\\
{}&{{x_i},a,b,c,d \in \left\{ {0,1} \right\}}
\end{array}
\end{array}$

For more information, a larger scale of this problem with $x_7$, $x_8$ and $x_9$ would make the matrix $A$ into this form which is quite sparse:

$\underbrace {\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&1&0&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}\\
0&1&1&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}\\
{}&{}&{}&1&1&0&{}&{}&{}\\
{}&{}&{}&0&1&1&{}&{}&{}\\
{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&1&1&0\\
{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&0&1&1
\end{array}} \right]}_A\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{x_1}}\\
{{x_2}}\\
{{x_3}}\\
{{x_4}}\\
{{x_5}}\\
{{x_6}}\\
{{x_7}}\\
{{x_8}}\\
{{x_9}}
\end{array}} \right] \ge \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
a\\
b\\
c\\
d\\
e\\
f
\end{array}} \right]$

The constraints on $a,b,c,d,e,f$ of the larger case would look like this

$\begin{array}{l}
a + c + e \le 1\\
b + d + f \le 1
\end{array}$

Or this

$\begin{array}{l}
a + c + e = 1\\
b + d + f = 1
\end{array}$

Would you kindly help me with this ?

Thank you for your enthusiam !

Comment: Are $a,b,c,d$ given values and $x_j$ decision variables? If so, what prevents you to solve the "size 1" problem by hand and then just combine the solutions of $n$ such problems into one?

Comment: A b c d are also decision variables but in some special situation, I can pre-solve them so that they become a given value. Could you elaborate more on this size 1 tactic ?

Comment: @RobPratt I have editted my question regarding $a,b,c,d,e,f$ for clarity. $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are just some control variables from a previous question that you have successfully help me.  Sorry for not posting the link in the first draft of the question, I have editted my question probably.

Comment: OK, my answer below still applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 1 is trivial: set all variables to $0$, yielding optimal objective value $0$.

Case 2 is almost as trivial.  The zero solution is infeasible, but you can set $x_2=a=b=1$ and all other variables $0$, yielding optimal objective value $1$.