# Is there a matrix that shift data along side the main diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, kronecker-product

I am an electrical engineer and I am trying to write my [optimization problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4814702/does-this-binary-integer-problem-has-any-special-structure-that-can-be-exploit) in a more compact form. During my time solving this optimization problem, I reallize that I need to keep shifting and augmenting my original data matrix $D = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&1&0\\
0&1&1
\end{array}} \right]$ along side the diagonal of a resulting matrix like this $R = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&1&0&{}&{}&{}\\
0&1&1&{}&{}&{}\\
{}&{}&{}&1&1&0\\
{}&{}&{}&0&1&1
\end{array}} \right]$ or $R = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&1&0&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}\\
0&1&1&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}\\
{}&{}&{}&1&1&0&{}&{}&{}\\
{}&{}&{}&0&1&1&{}&{}&{}\\
{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&1&1&0\\
{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&0&1&1
\end{array}} \right]$.

So my question is: is there a matrix $T$ or transformation $T(D)$ that help me achieve my goal ?

I guess it might have something to do with the Kronecker product but cannot get my head around it.

Would you kindly help me with this ?

Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Comment: Are you looking for a shift matrix? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_matrix

Comment: To be honest I dont even know how to state my problem mathematically

Comment: The question seems fairly clear. You have a matrix $D$ and you want to form a matrix $R_n$ that has $n$ copies of $D$ along its diagonal (and zeros elsewhere, I’d guess). You want a formula or process for producing $R_n$, given $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a matrix $T$ or transformation $T(D)$ ... might have something to do with the Kronecker product

Using [Direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_addition#Direct_sum): $$R_n=\bigoplus_{i=1}^{n}D$$
$$R_{n+1}=R_n\oplus D$$

Using [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product):
$$R_n=I_n\otimes D$$

Comment: Thank you, this answer $R_n=I_n\otimes D$  suits my need.